# How to match over Pin<Type> in Rust?

Tags: rust

I was trying to do this:

```
use std::pin::Pin;

enum A{
    AA,
    BB,
    CC
}

fn main() {
    let a = Pin::new(A::AA);
    match a{
        Pin<AA> => {},
        Pin<BB> => {},
        Pin<CC> => {}
    }
}
```

until I realized I don't understand what's happening. How can I match over the variants inside `Pin`?

Error:

```
error: expected one of `=>`, `@`, `if`, or `|`, found `<`
  --> src/main.rs:13:12
   |
13 |         Pin<AA> => {},
   |            ^ expected one of `=>`, `@`, `if`, or `|`
```

Comment: You can't store the `A` type, as defined, in a `Pin`, because it's not a pointer type. Did you mean to store a reference or a `Box<A>`, perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, as @SilvioMayolo mentioned, you can't pin your enum directly, because [`Pin<P>` requres `P: Deref`.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/struct.Pin.html#impl)
If you fix that by putting your enum in a `Box` and pinning that, you will be able to match on your pinned value by dereferencing it, [because `Pin` is `Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/struct.Pin.html#impl-Deref):

```
enum A {
    AA,
    BB,
    CC,
}

fn main() {
    let a = Box::pin(A::AA);
    match *a {
        A::AA => {}
        A::BB => {}
        A::CC => {}
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8191a05d2674c8bc5adb507889c27a73)